# Can RestSharp obtain an oauth2 access token from IdentityServer/DuendeServer for a user programmatically if given username/password?

Tags: api, restsharp, duende-identity-server

We have Duende server for our UI and users provide their username and password and obtain an access token that is then used by our SPA app to call api's with the access token issued by our identity server.

I'm in a situation where I need to call the same API from a script and was wondering if RestSharp has some capability to obtain an access token if provided certain information (perhaps the users email/password etc that are typically entered into an interactive website) ?

I see that the RestSharp has some OAuth related "authenticators" but the documentation is unclear exactly what they achieve.  I also dont see it mentioning anything about an email address and password.

I'm wondering if theres an option that is different than me generating a JWT elsewhere and supplying it directly to restsharp.  I'd love if there was a programmatic way to generate the token directly from the IDP.

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp documentation doesn't make it secret about how authenticators work. Both [OAuth2 authenticators](https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#oauth2) only add the necessary header or query string using the token you provide, but they don't request the token.

Duende server documentation [explains in detail](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/password_grant/) how to get a token based on the password grant (which is using the username and password).

Although the OAuth2 spec is stable, each API vendor has its own limitations. For example, Twitter API v2 only supports the `client_credentials` grant type.  Therefore, it's not easy to create a generic OAuth2 client.

Still, it's quite easy to amend the [Twitter authenticator sample](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#authenticator) from the docs and extend both request and response models to support the Duende server token request endpoint.